# Is there any way to recover overwritten notes on mac?

Tags: command-line, notes.app, zip, sqlite

I pasted something on top of a note on my Mac that had some moderately important stuff, switched notes (which means no `ctrl-z`), and I'm trying to recover it. My first mistake is that I unfortunately don't have a backup that includes it (iCloud or Time Machine.)

So far I've:

- tracked down the NoteStore.sqlite (-wal, -shm) which, as far as I can tell from googling, acts as a change log for all your notes along with the -wal which stores overflow
- managed to extract the data stored in blobs from ZICNOTEDATA (`select hex(zdata) from ZICNOTEDATA`)
- realized each row is the raw version of a .gz (starts with `1F8B0800000...`)

And this is where I'm stuck now, probably because I don't have the right vocabulary to google it. Ideally, I want to put each row of this sqlite column into a "real" gzip in a folder somewhere, unzip them all into .txt files, and view as the original note. If not, I can go one-by-one and unzip them until I find the one I need. Also, I'd like to avoid any external software.

Any ideas or easier ways to do this? Thanks!

Comment: did you paste an image on top of your note or just text. i'm confused about how you lost original note,  If an image can't you just remove what you pasted?

Comment: @jmh sorry, it's confusing. 
I had two different notes (Note A, my important note, and Note B, a wall of code I'm working on at the moment) at the top of my most recently edited notes list on the left. 
I went to update Note B with a new version, so I `ctrl-A` `ctrl-V`, but I still had Note A open. I then created Note C. When I went back to Note A and realized my mistake (it was now the new version of Note B), there was no option to undo, as I had already left the note I accidentally changed.

Comment: You don't have any backup apps running?

Comment: @jmh unfortunately no :( not a mistake I'll make again.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s gone. Notes Auto-Saves and immediately syncs changes to all devices in the cloud. TimeMachine would be your saving grace here